# Associative Arrays sent via php POST aren't complete

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post, associative-array

I have a a dynamic form with a handful of text inputs that share names (for example, "lessons[] and "outlines[]". When I validate after submitting, I print everything to console and it's all there. But in my submit.php, many of the associative arrays stored in post only have about the first 20% of the data that they should.

This is the very last thing I do when validating the form to make sure everything is there (and it is). Structures is 5, all 5 outlines are present, and all 41 lessons are there. It's all accurate and what I expect to see.

```
var structures = document.getElementsByName("structure[]");
console.log("Structures: " + structures.length);

console.log("OUTLINES")
var outline_ids = document.getElementsByName("outline_ids[]");
var outlines = document.getElementsByName("outlines[]");
for (var i = 0; i < outlines.length; i++){
    console.log(outline_ids[i].value + ": " + outlines[i].value);
}

console.log("LESSONS");
var lessons = document.getElementsByName("lessons[]");
var section_info = document.getElementsByName("section_info[]");
for (var i = 0; i < lessons.length; i++){
    console.log(lessons[i].value + ": " + section_info[i].value);
}

return true;
```

Then, at the top of the submit php script, I run `print_r($_POST);` and see that:

structure only has 2 values instead of all 5

outline_ids has 2 instead of 5

outlines has 1 instead of 5

both lessons and section_info have only 8 values instead of 41

There are zero lines of code between returning true in validation, and printing POST in the submit script. Any ideas why so much data is being lost in POST? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: In the form script, the form itself has the tag `<form name="form" action="course_submit.php?courseID=<?php echo $id?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">` in case that helps.

Comment: Look at your browser inspector to see what is being sent.

Comment: Right. Going to Network -> Response shows the same POST as I'm printing, which is to say, a bunch of the info is missing. So for some reason, POST isn't sending all of the data. Thank you for the reminder that I can check there instead of printing it, though! That is cleaner.

Comment: So your javascript isn't sending the data correctly. I don't see any code here that's sending a request.

Comment: Added the form tag to the end of my post.

Comment: Though, all of the data IS present under Headers for course_submit.php

Comment: How much is “a handful” here? With a large number of parameters, you might be running into a limit such as [`max_input_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

Comment: By a "handful", I mean, maybe 100 total between the 5ish variables. So I doubt I'm running into any limits. And since data is missing from all the arrays, instead of the last one being truncated, I think some other bug is at play here.